# assets are fetched without the hash code appended while using Grails CDN Asset Pipeline Plugin

Tags: grails, amazon-s3, cdn, grails-plugin

I recently configured this plugin on my project. The assets in my S3 bucket are uploaded with some random hash code appended to them. However while retrieving them the hash code are not being appended in the request. As a result it shows the resource not found error in the console. 
I am using Asset Pipeline 2.1.1.

Comment: Can you show how you use js, css or image file in gsp? I mean which tag you use 'asset' or 'resource'.

Comment: This is my code snippet from index.gsp <asset:javascript src="site/site.js" />
    <asset:javascript src="common/mordnizr.js" />
    <asset:stylesheet href="site/site.css" />

Comment: Are you running it in development mode or creating war and running in separate tomcat?

Comment: It is running fine while running the war in production mode now.

Comment: Does It mean you have that problem running it in development mode?

Comment: Yes. Even the command grails prd run-app dosent helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [asset pipeline plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) adds hash value at the end of asset file name when war file is created. So `run-app` or `prod run-app` will not help you as war is not created for these commands.

For that to work, you can use `run-war` or `prod run-war` command. Otherwise you have to create war and deploy in external tomcat.

If you look the [documentation of grails cdn asset pipeline plugin](https://github.com/agorapulse/grails-cdn-asset-pipeline), it shows

```
grails.assets.url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/assets/${appName}-${appVersion}"
```

But this should be only used for production mode but not for development mode. Example taken from [asset pipeline plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) :

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.assets.url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/asset-pipe/assets/"
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i use for development if I want to? Building a war file again after a small change is really time consuming task

Comment: Generally cdn is not used for development purpose because we do change continuously on assets. It is only used for production purpose in order to load static content fast using distributed network.